# Contributing to JHipster

Tags: jhipster

I would contribute to the JHipster project adding catalan properties for i18n. However, my IDE prevents me from doing so when I try to import a project because there is no pom.xml (there is a _pom.xml).
I don't understand why an underscore was added to the pom.xml filename. Does someone know the reason?

**Updated:**

I guess it's because it's not a Maven Java project. So where I can find documentation about how to compile and test my changes?

Comment: What IDE is preventing you?

Comment: my IDE is IntelliJ Idea

Comment: That would be a way to let people modify their local pom.xml but not committing it?

Comment: If you want prevent commits of pom.xml you would add to .gitignore, don't you?

Comment: You must've already discovered (judging from [the PR you submitted](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/469)) that JHipster is a Maven application Yeoman generator written in JavaScript, not a Maven application itself. You must've been trying to import it into your IDE as a Maven project while it should be a "generic" project (unless there's a dedicated Yeoman and/or JavaScript project type)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a Yeoman generator, so the best way to learn about contributing is by looking at the Yeoman "authoring" page: http://yeoman.io/authoring/

As you will create templates (like the _pom.xml file you are mentionning), most IDEs will not work properly. Here is how I work:

- I generate a "sample" project
- I write some working code
- I do a "diff", and manually apply it to my template
- I generate again the project, with the new template, to see if I get the same result
- And of course I test the generated project!

Comment: Since this answer, we have instructions here: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md